# Traveling to Pakistan on Emirates from US (recently tested positive)

Tags: usa, air-travel, covid-19, emirates, pakistan

Please point me to the correct post if it was recently asked;

**Problem/Scenario**:

- recently tested positive
- fully vaccinated
- planning to take Emirates to Karachi
- Pakistan wants a PCR test

as per [CDC FAQs](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/faqs.html)...

> People can continue to test positive for up to 90 days after a COVID-19 diagnosis without being infectious to others. For this reason, travelers who have recovered from COVID-19 in the past 90 days do not need to get tested before or after travel.

**Question**:
what if I get a positive results (before going to Pakistan) - or Positive result on the way back...

- will Emirates stop me from boarding?
- will Pakistan stop me from entering?
- will Dubai be a problem during transit

Emirates' website has been ambiguous and they have an automated message on their helpline and they're not answering the phone - can someone help?

Comment: Have you taken a covid test recently? Did it come back positive or negative? If the former, do you have a documentation of recovery signed by your doctor?

Comment: [Pakistan's policy](https://storage.covid.gov.pk/uploads/policies/Revised%20Testing%20Protocols%20Inbound%20and%20Outbound%20Travels.pdf), as linked [from the Emirates site](https://www.emirates.com/us/english/help/covid-19/travel-requirements-by-destination/), seems to be absolute that a negative PCR test is required before boarding; it doesn't say anything about an exception to this requirement if you have documentation of a recent recovery from COVID. Unless someone finds an exception of this nature, you may unfortunately not be able to travel until you can test negative on a PCR test.

Comment: didn't take a PCR at the end of self-isolation @mlc;

Comment: @ZachLipton I think that's an answer.

Comment: yeah, I think I would have to take the risk of PCR test - thanks a lot @ZachLipton

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope you're feeling better!

[Pakistan's testing policy](https://storage.covid.gov.pk/uploads/policies/Revised%20Testing%20Protocols%20Inbound%20and%20Outbound%20Travels.pdf) seems to be absolute that a negative PCR test is required for all inbound passengers (except deportees and those under 6 years old, and I assume you're neither of those). Nothing in that document, which is linked from [the country's travel guidelines page](https://covid.gov.pk/travel-guidelines), itself [linked from the Emirates site](https://www.emirates.com/us/english/help/covid-19/travel-requirements-by-destination/), says there's any sort of exemption to this requirement, like the one allowed by the US CDC, available for people with documentation of a recent recovery from COVID.

Unless someone is aware of a policy of this nature, you may unfortunately be unable to travel until you're able to test negative on a PCR test. If you need to travel soon, it may be worth [contacting one of Pakistan's listed contacts](https://covid.gov.pk/travel-guidelines) to ask about any possibility of an exemption (though you would also need to satisfy the airline and potentially the transit country).

While it's possible to test positive on PCR tests for 90 days after infection, it's more likely that it won't take that long, so it's probably worth trying to get another test to see where things stand.

Comment: Thanks... I don't like the outcome but love your response and help :)